# Database restructure - beneficial?

Tags: mysql

I have a table for email messages. Then, I have a table that has the `message parts`.

The `Parts` table contains a

```
   field_id,  message_id, and data
```

**At the time I used Parts to name the table and yet used field_id for the column. Just an FYI**

So for example, a `part_id` of 2 would be the subject of the message. 
I have parts for `subject`, `date`, `htmlbody`, and `textbody`. Due to this structure, I have approximately 2 more queries per email (one for the parts, and another for the email addresses associated to the email) than if I were to push all the data into the messages tables. I found this structure to be best, but I'm beginning to think it might be wrong and not best for performance.

**My question is, will it be in my best interests to restructure the database?** Id rather not.

I was thinking about moving the `htmlbody` and `textbody` and `subject` and `date` to the `messages table`. Another solution would be to grab all the `emails` and their `data` from the `Parts` table in one query. I could grab all the ids in one query and then do an IN(ids) for the second query.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `messages` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `account_folder_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `uid` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `seen` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `flagged` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `message_parts_data` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `message_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `field_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fields` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `fields` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'To'),
(2, 'Subject'),
(3, 'Date'),
(4, 'From'),
(5, 'CC'),
(7, 'ReplyTo'),
(8, 'textHtml'),
(9, 'textPlain'),
(11, 'Forward');
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no belief system for normalization; it's either normalized or it's not.

Comment: I think you should provide sample data more than the query itself first. In that regard we could focus if your Database really need re-structuring or not. Then we could move on to refining your query later if you could show it also.

Comment: I updated my question. Im pretty sure theres no redundant data, but Im not going to claim its normalized so i just took that out. @Edper I'll get some data tomorrow around 3pm.

Comment: So the `data` column stores data for all `subject`, `date`, `htmlbody`, and `textbody`, right? This looks like EAV structure. Please add the design of all the relevant tables you have (`Messages`, `Parts`, whatever else), even better the `CREATE TABLE` statements.

Comment: Added the messages,fields, and message parts table SQL.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you the best structure for your data because I don't know all your needs, however, I can tell you how I structured my tables for a similar project that had to store a scalable amount of email messages in a searchable form that may or may not be geographically distributed. This is what we did:

There was a `messages` table consisting of a unique `message_id` as primary key, as well as some fields to store information that was not contained in the message itself (data from the SMTP envelope) such as dates and times, sender, sending server, a few performance indicators, etc. Additionally, there was a `storage_id`, to indicate which storage structure contained the parts/attachments (usually a folder path, but could be a schema-based address, such as `sftp://user@host/path/to/folder`).

Next was the `headers` table which stored one message header line per row. This contained a unique `header_id` as primary key, as well as a `message_id` (indexed) that linked back to a record in the `messages` table. There was a `header_name` field (indexed), which contained the header name (eg: "Subject", "From", etc), and a `header_text` field, which contained the text of the header. There was also a `sequence` number (indexed) that was used to indicate the order of the headers. Due to our need to search these headers, we used fulltext indexing on `header_text`.

Then there was a `parts_text` table which stored only the text parts of a message. This table had a unique `part_id` as primary key, a `message_id`, a `sequence` and some fields for storing mime types and part-markers, and the `part_body` field, which stored the entire text. This field was fulltext indexed, however in the long term we planned to run the message's text parts through a lucene indexing process and just store the results in the db, with the actual text part stored as a file in the area designated by the message's `storage_id`.

Then there was a `parts_binary` table which stored the same things as the `parts_text` table but without the part_body. That was stored as a file in the area designated by the message's `storage_id`. Note that the `sequence` in this table would be interspersed with the `sequence` from the `parts_text` table.

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but this structure worked for us so maybe it can be of some help to you.